# How to specify filter priorities in java web apps?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

Hello I wish I could define two filters like this

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

with the same pattern /* in my web.xml file, and I wish I could be sure the SecurityFilter will be executed before the other. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just did. From Sun's [XSD](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd):

> The order in which filters are invoked
>   is the order in which filter-mapping
>   declarations that match a request URI
>   for a servlet appear in the list of
>   filter-mapping elements.